# No Creators Exist: Cannot Deserialize

Tags: spring-boot

I got an error ...`(no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)` which indicates that I need a property-based creator. I have a few constructors with different parameters, but no default.

My solution was to add a default constructor `SomeClass() {}`. My question is: why does this happen? Also, what is a delegate/property-based constructor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there is no constructors that is annotated with `@JsonCreator`, by default, Jackson needs a default no-args constructor in order to parse the JSON into POJO or bean classes. That is why when you add a default constructor, it will work fine.

And if you don't actually need the usage of the default constructor, just add it for Jackson only, you can set it to `private`, `protected` or `package-protected`. Jackson is still able to fill all the fields via reflection.

Regarding the `no delegate- or property-based Creator`, they are constructors that is annotated with `@JsonCreator`. In Jackson, there are 2 types of Creator/JsonCreator which are `delegate-based Creator` and `property-based Creator`.

> Delegate-based creators take just one argument, which is NOT annotated with @JsonProperty. Type of that property is used by Jackson to bind the whole JSON value (JSON Object, array or scalar value), to be passed as value of that one argument.

> Property-based creators take one or more arguments; all of which MUST be annotated with @JsonProperty, to specify JSON name used for property. They can only be used to bind data from JSON Objects; and each parameter represents one property of the JSON Object; type of property being used for binding data to be passed as that parameter when calling creator.

You can read for more details about these 2 creators in the article below.
http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_457.html