# Akka, Jackson cannot deserialise "ordinary classes"

Tags: java, json, jackson, akka

Trying to deserialize my actor commands via the out of the box `jackson-json` serialiser. I am able to get the expected result with a lot of annotation while it should be much easier:

> In many cases ordinary classes can be serialized by Jackson without any additional hints, but sometimes annotations are needed to specify how to convert the objects to JSON/bytes.
>
> -- https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/serialization-jackson.html#introduction

---

The example is similar to my use case. However, if I do not put all annotations on my command, the serialisation fail.

- Class file (Java)

```
    package org.example;

    // ...

    class ExampleAR extends EventSourcedBehaviorWithEnforcedReplies<ExampleAR.Command, ExampleAR.Event, ExampleAR.State> {

      // ...
 
      interface Command { /* Nothing here */ }

      public static class CreateExample implements Command {
        final SecurityClaims claims;
        final ExampleRef ref;
        final String title;
        final ActorRef<StatusReply<ExampleCreated>> replyTo;

        public CreateExample(
                SecurityClaims claims,
                ExampleRef ref,
                String title,
                ActorRef<StatusReply<ExampleCreated>> replyTo) {
            this.claims = claims;
            this.ref = ref;
            this.title = title;
            this.replyTo = replyTo;
        }
      }

      // ...

    }
```

- Configuration file

```
    akka.actor {
      serialization-bindings {
        "org.example.ExampleAR$Command" = jackson-json
      }
    }
```

Message :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Command [org.example.ExampleAR$CreateExample@20251fb0] isn't serializable.,
...
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.example.ExampleAR$CreateExample` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

---

Please, **note** that I do understand the error message. And I can decorate my commands my `@JsonCreator` and other `@JsonProperty` annotations. However, the documentation state that those will not be required for simple cases while it is not in my case.

I may have missed a configuration or another dependency that will enable simple serialisation..

Comment: You claim you understand the error message; how about the part `no Creators, like default constructor, exist`?

Comment: @Thomas as said, the example in https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/serialization-jackson.html#usage looks similar to my use case. They also have one message without any default constructor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Creators Exist: Cannot Deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70690443/no-creators-exist-cannot-deserialize)

Comment: I'am afraid but no. I guess my question is not clear enough. I understand the cause and how to solve the deserialisation issue. However, I do not understand why Akka say it should work without annotations. Are they wrong in the doc or am I missing something to have the result that they describe .

Comment: Did you add the -parameters compiler option to your build as mentioned in the end of the referenced doc section? I think that could potentially avoid the need for creator annotations.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: Are you using Scala 3.x? Try using Scala 2.13.x

I don't know if this is your case, but I had a similar error and finally got the culprit: I was trying to use Akka + Akka HTTP + Persistent actors (with event sourcing). As Akka HTTP doesn't yet have a Scala 3.x version I had to include all these dependencies using `CrossVersion`:

```scala
  libraryDependencies ++= {
    ... // versions
    Seq(
      "com.typesafe.akka"  %% "akka-http"                   % akkaHttpVersion,
      "com.typesafe.akka"  %% "akka-http-spray-json"        % akkaHttpVersion,
      "com.typesafe.akka"  %% "akka-actor-typed"            % akkaVersion,
      ... // you already get it
    ).map(_.cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13)) ++ Seq(
      ... // other dependencies
    )
```

As I guessed this could be causing the problem I migrated my code to Scala 2.13.x, after that it worked without any problem.